# HTML form action on part of form

Tags: html, forms

I'm making a form and want something to happen when just a certain part of the form has been completed.  I've got some checkboxes, a dropdown menu, and three read-only text fields.  I need something to pop up when the checkboxes and dropdown fields have been populated, but have no idea how to do this.  I tried putting a form within a form, but after that failed and I later read up on the matter, I found that to be impractical.  Anyhow, here's my code for the form:

```
<form action="http://siedb1.sys.virginia.edu/~jhr3ct/Code/Reserve%20Confirmation.php">
        Facility: <input type="checkbox" name="facility" value="AFC">AFC
        <input type="checkbox" name="facility" value="Memorial Gym">Memorial Gym
        <input type="checkbox" name="facility" value="Slaughter">Slaughter
        <input type="checkbox" name="facility" value="North Grounds">North Grounds<br>
        Type of Room/Court: 
        <select>
            <option value="default">Choose room...</option>
            <option value="squash">Squash</option>
            <option value="handball">Handball</option>
            <option value="racquetball">Racquetball</option>
            <option value="multipurpose">Multipurpose</option>
        </select><br>
        Room: <input type="text" name="start" readonly="readonly"><br>
        Start Time: <input type="text" name="start" readonly="readonly"><br>
        End Time: <input type="text" name="end" readonly="readonly"><br><br>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just check the elements using a javascript, if they are filled, trigger the action

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never used JavaScript.  Though if you could point in to a source where I could learn to do something like that it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Search some nice tutorial on interactive forms on google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be interested in learning basic javascript form events. There is many tutorials on internet. I suggest you this one: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/select.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show a popup after all check boxes are checked and the dropdown is changed add this kind of a function to the onclick events of all the check boxes and onchange event of the dropdown box.

> function func() {
>             var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
>          var dropdowns = document.getElementsByTagName('SELECT');
>          for (var i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++) {
>               if (inputTags[i].type == 'checkbox') {
>                        var aCheckBox = inputTags[i];
>                        if(!aCheckBox.checked) {
>                             return;
>                        }
>                }
>          }
>          if(dropdowns[0].value == 'default') {
>                return;
>          }   
>          alert("All checkboxes and dropdowns are filled.");
>   }
>
> `<form action="../Confirmation.php">`
>                `<input onclick="func()" type="checkbox" name="facility" value="AFC">AFC`
>                `<input onclick="func()" type="checkbox" name="facility"`
>                    `value="Slaughter">Slaughter`
>                `<select onchange="func()" id="ss">`
>   `</form>`

Answer (score 0):

Just to point you in the right direction: You will have to use javascript to check your form inputs values, and to show a pop-up window.

You could use jQuery to do that easily, and make a listener for the form submit() action, where you could check if your checkboxes and dropdown are selected.

The jQuery doc is here: http://api.jquery.com/submit/